# Об этнохоронимах

Tags: грамотная-речь

В Эквадоре есть город Кока. Как можно назвать его жителей и, в частности, продавцов (например, в Москве — московские)?

Answer (score 2):

Жители Коки, продавцы в Коке (добродушные) - это не будет ошибкой. Новообразования же для русского читателя будут звучать недостаточно серьёзно, а с местными жителями невозможно было бы согласовать устраивающее их русское наименование (кокавитяне по аналогии со сложившимся "ословитяне" или что-то подобное).

Comment: Непонятно, откуда это, и кто решил, что "ословитянами" можно называть...

Comment: Да бросьте, жители Осло - ***о***слинцы, ***о***слинец, ***о***слинка.

Comment: Опа... Уже так...)))) А я в Интернете нашёл больше упоминаний об ословцах. "Ослинцев" вообще не видел. Но я не хочу сказать, что мне "ословцы" больше нравятся, не знаю, как лучше, пока. Или про "ослинцев" шутка такая?))))))

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да нет, если ***так***, то ***ещё***. ))) Такой вариант был единственно нормативным лет двадцать назад. Кстати, "Справка" в пору своего расцвета подтверждала со ссылкой на какой-то авторитетный словарь. Но это была в первых ста тысячах вопросах, базу которых они потом благополучно угробили.

Comment: Хотя сейчас, согласен, Лопатин дает форму "ословский", а не "ослинский". И следовательно, ословец. И хотя это вообще не лопатинская тема, приходится считаться. Да и сама "Грамота" непоследовательна. http://www.gramota.ru/class/olimpic/contest02/35_43 Не знаю, короче. Но мне вариант "ослинцы" явно не приснился. И на слух приятнее.

Comment: Интересно это всё. Да, звучит красиво.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Александр прав, только вот продавцов, по-моему, всё-таки можно назвать *"кокскими".* А вот с жителями действительно сложно. Придумывать что-то своё однозначно неправильно. Если придумают для этого города название составители словарей, тогда будет ясно, как называть, а так да — только "жители Коки".

Answer (score 0):

В чем Alex_ander прав, так это в том, что не на каждый город катойконим (название жителей)  придумали. Но коли выбирать из чего-то, то давайте от печки.
Если ударение на последний слог, то напрашивается кок**а**нцы, кок**а**нец, кок**а**нка (женский род - не так очевидно), коканский.

А вот если ударение на первом слоге, то прилагательное, похоже, кокский, а жители - кокцы, кокец, кокчка (тоже под большим вопросом) и кокский.
Но это догадки. Лучше не использовать то, что более чем сомнительно.

Comment: Конечно, ударение на первый слог, там же испанский язык.